# SQL-I need to update a totals table with the difference between two columns in a status table by date.

Tags: mysql, sql

In my current schema (below), I need to automatically update the pc12_totals table with the hobbs_end - hobbs_start per date from the pc12_status table. I am not sure which type of join to use and how to subtract in sql.

```
CREATE TABLE  pc12_status (hobbs_start decimal(5,2) NOT NULL, 
                       hobbs_end decimal(5,2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
                       landings int(5) NOT NULL,
                       engine_cycles int(5) NOT NULL,
                       flight_date date NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (1.2, 1.7, 6, 2, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (1.7, 2.3, 2, 1, "1987-12-17");
INSERT INTO pc12_status VALUES (2.3, 3.4, 3, 1, "1987-12-18");

CREATE TABLE pc12_totals (flight_hours decimal (5,2) NOT NULL,
                         landings_total int (5) NOT NULL,
                         engine_cycles int(5) NOT NULL,
                         flight_date date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
```

Comment: When you want to update the pc12_totals table ? When a new row in pc12_status is created ? If yes you can use triggers for that. Give more details.

Comment: I would like the pc12_totals table to automatically update every time the pc12_status table is updated.

Answer (score 1):

First your `pc12_totals` has no any identity column which could reference the `pc12_status` table. So for instance you want `insert` statement rather than `update`

```
insert into pc12_totals (flight_hours , landings_total , engine_cycles , flight_date)
select sum(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours ,
       sum(landings) landings_total,   sum(engine_cycles) engine_cycles , flight_date
from pc12_status
group by flight_date
```

Once `pc12_totals` get data so, you could do the `JOIN`s by `flight_date`

```
update pc12_totals 
inner join 
(
  select sum(hobbs_end - hobbs_start) flight_hours ,
         sum(landings) landings_total,   sum(engine_cycles) engine_cycles , flight_date
  from pc12_status
  group by flight_date 
) s on s.flight_date = t.flight_date
set t.flight_hours = s.flight_hours, ...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly to insert the data I already have into the new table. But when I tried to add more data into the pc12_status table, it did not automatically update the totals table. How would I make it automatic (say if a user were to input data into the status table tomorrow)?

Comment: @RachelHamm... `I make it automatic ` (i.e. you want `trigger` ?)

Comment: @RachelHamm you can create insert/update trigger on pc12_status table this trigger will automatically execute when any row in pc12_status is updated. Write the Yogesh Sharma's first code inside that trigger.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER upd_total AFTER INSERT ON pc12_status
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO pc12_totals (flight_hours, flight_date)
SELECT SUM(hobbs_end-hobbs_start) flight_hours, flight_date
FROM pc12_status
GROUP BY flight_date;    ???????????????????

Comment: The trigger above worked but now I am receiving multiple entries per date. I need the total of the difference values for each day.